# Regex for mod_rewrite to only take whats before --

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi i have url that reads like

```
/users/nick--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html
```

what i need is to make regex that takes nick even if its like this

```
ni-ck--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html
```

1. bla-bla might be any number of variables i just need to get "nick" part regardless what follows it because it will be always separated by "--".
2. nick only up to 50 characters

Can someone suggest working regex for mod-rewrite, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

If the URL will always have a nick, last, first and middle, followed by optional vars and the nick must be from 1 to 50 chars, then this tested rule will work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^users/((?:(?!--)[^/]){1,50})--([^-/]+)-([^-/]+)-([^-/]+)([^/]*)$ index.php?nick=$1&last=$2&first=$3&middle=$4&vars=$5 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Given: `/users/ni-ck--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` this rule separates out and provides the following `$_GET` array variables:

```
Array
(
    [nick] => ni-ck
    [last] => last
    [first] => first
    [middle] => middle
    [vars] => -bla-bla-bla.html
)
```

### Option 2:

If the URL will always have a nick from 1 to 50 chars, followed by `"--"`and everything following that is optional, then this tested rule will work. (This one does not separate out the name parts):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^users/((?:(?!--)[^/]){1,50})--([^/]*)$ index.php?nick=$1&vars=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Given: `/users/ni-ck--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` this rule separates out and provides the following `$_GET` array variables:

```
Array
(
    [nick] => ni-ck
    [vars] => last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/users/((?:-?[0-9a-zA-Z]){,50})
```

Should capture your nick in $1. (Don't remember if the non capturing parenthesis work in mod-Rewrite, or else just loose the `?:` )

Comment: Hum, this is not perfect in term of number of char. But this limit the alpha-num chars to 50. (Meaning - does not count in the 50 limit)

Answer (score 0):

`^/users/(.{0,50}).*(?=--)(?<!--.*)` matches the "nick" part up to 50 characters or up to `--` (whichever is shortest) in a group, using quantifiers and lookarounds for the constraints.

`^/users/`: match the start string
`(.{0,50})`: match any character, up to 50, into this group
`.*`: match any character after the 50th
but only match until `--` (not inclusive):
`(?=--)`: positive lookahead, `--` exists immediately after this location
`(?<!--.*)`: negative lookbehind, `--` does not exist anywhere before this location

Note that the `--` is required or the pattern will not match.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. I was getting error 500 internal server error when i used it. Had to remove last part (?<!--.*) or remove star from it to make it work. can i use .html instead of .* ?

Comment: First I think you need to understand what the pattern expresses, before just trying to change anything… So head on over to http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html to read about it, and then play with it in your code or on http://nregex.com/ or on http://regexhero.net/tester

Comment: Perhaps you can try escaping one or more of the dashes/hyphens in the last part and see if that helps: `(?<!\-\-.*)`

Comment: Or maybe mod_rewrite just does not support negative lookbehind?

Comment: \-\- does not help. also if -- occured several times "name--last--first..." is there way to make regex to read only up to first name--?

Answer (score 0):

Try following rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/(.{1,50}?)-- /foo.php?name=$1 [L]
```

## TESTING

If I have foo.php like this:

```
<?php var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]); ?>
```

1. For the URL of `/users/nicked-ic-ic-ack--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` it prints:

   string(21) "name=nicked-ic-ic-ack"
2. For the URL of `/users/ni-ck--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` it prints:

   string(10) "name=ni-ck"
3. For the URL of `/users/nick--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` it prints:

   string(9) "name=nick"
4. For the URL `/users/nick--last--first` **(multiple `--`)** it prints:

   string(9) "name=nick"
5. For the URL of `/users/nicked-ic-ic-nicked-nicked-nicked-nicked-nicked-nicked-nicked-ack--last-first-middle-bla-bla-bla.html` it **throws 404** since length of name is now > 50

   404 - Not found

Comment: Thanks this works too, but somewhat wrong since folder users exist and has file css/main.css and file foo.php is outside of folder when page opens it does not read css/main.css even though its right there at site.com/users/css/main.css                 also i dont need to remove any caracters from the name it should be as is.

Comment: Alright I just updated my answer as per your comment. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Would this still work if `--` occured several times? "nick--last--first…"

Comment: @mousio: Yes it will work with `--` occurring several times. Please see test case # 4 above.

Answer (score 0):

`^/users/(?(.{0,50}?--)(.*?)|(.{50}).+)--` does not work with lookarounds but instead uses lazy quantifiers and a conditional (I do not know if either is supported by mod_rewrite) which puts either the short nick in group 1 or the cut off nick in group 2, so you can just concatenate those groups to get the requested nick.

`^/users/`: match the start string
`(?`: start of the conditional expression
`(.{0,50}?--)`: [*if*] check if we have a short nick here (no more than 50 characters before first `--`)
`(.*?)`: [*then*] match any character into this group (until first `--`, see below, due to lazy matching)
`|`: delimiter in the conditional expression
`(.{50}).+`: [*else*] only match first 50 characters into this group
`)`: end of the conditional expression
`--`: final match

---

Actually it is not really clear what to do with nicks that are too long. If long nicks can just be ignored instead of cut off, then maybe the following suffices?

`^/users/(.{0,50}?)--` only matches short nicks in the first group (lazy quantifier)…